# Doing something on time intervals, but only when user is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

I have a table with some rows that I want to refresh for example every 10 minutes. Is there a way I can do this, but only if the user isn't currently active on that page?

Is there for example anything like an inactivity timer or something in JavaScript?

Comment: @Peter J's answer looks most interesting in that question

Comment: @pekka: I disagree, I don't think mouse movement should be the basis of idle time. When reading a page, I use me keyboard for scrolling and my mouse for links.

Comment: @Andy good point! The solution fails there. The Idle time plugin linked by @Moin claims to listen to keypress events too.

Comment: Yeah, seems like that is about what I'm asking. Voting to close as well :)

Comment: @Pekka: yes, I would think a combination of keydown and mousemove events should work well enough for idle time.  At least, I can't think of any other way of not being idle on a web page :-)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use this and accomplish what you need:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

have a look at the options and the `onIdle` option, adding your function here should do the trick

Comment: this is likely to be closed as a duplicate. Why not add your answer in the other question as well? As far as I can see, it's not there yet and it's good info.