# How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` running a piece of code 30 times a second. This works great, however when I select another tab (so that the tab with my code becomes inactive), the `setInterval` is set to an idle state for some reason.

I made this simplified test case (http://jsfiddle.net/7f6DX/3/):

```
var $div = $('div');
var a = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    a++;
    $div.css("left", a)
}, 1000 / 30);
```

If you run this code and then switch to another tab, wait a few seconds and go back, the animation continues at the point it was when you switched to the other tab.

So the animation isn't running 30 times a second in case the tab is inactive. This can be confirmed by counting the amount of times the `setInterval` function is called each second - this will not be 30 but just 1 or 2 if the tab is inactive.

I guess that this is done by design so as to improve system performance, but is there any way to disable this behavior?

It’s actually a disadvantage in my scenario.

Comment: Probably not, unless you hacked it together with the `Date` object to really see what time has passed.

Comment: Could you explain more about your scenario? Maybe it's not such a disadvantage.

Comment: To be precise, I have a tictactoe game with multiplayer support. When A places a X in a field, a cross animation is being executed for both palyer A and B. When B does not have the tab with the game active, it isn't until B makes that tab active that the animation starts. It's not such a great deal but if there is a solution to make it work at any time I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You mean [this](http://codereview.chromium.org/6577021) code change, and what you ask is also discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/ff827011f2d1f0f6) - Oliver Mattos posted some work around, maybe it's valid in your case as well?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Thanks for those links, they are exactly what I was looking for. The answer provided here also just works fine.

Comment: Cheers, the answer you got is good indeed!

Comment: It's almost always best to key animations on the amount of real time elapsed since beginning of the animation, as read from `Date`. So that when intervals don't fire quickly (for this or other reasons) the animation just gets jerkier, not slower.

Comment: The title of the question led me here however my use case was a bit different - I needed an authentication token refreshed regardless of a tab's inactivity. If that is relevant for you check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883700/145599)

Comment: How to make a tab NEVER EVER stop running? I'm using "setTimeout", script speaks periodically, I am almost always away from the tab, script pated in console while "page" is "data:text/html,".
I toggled auto-discard off in discards - script dies eventually.
I'm looking for something like "kill everything and everyone EXCEPT THIS SCRIPT" - or anything close to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

On most browsers inactive tabs have low priority execution and this can affect JavaScript timers.

If the values of your transition were calculated using **real time elapsed between frames** instead fixed increments on each interval, you not only workaround this issue but also can achieve a smother animation by using [**requestAnimationFrame**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as it can get up to 60fps if the processor isn't very busy.

Here's a vanilla JavaScript example of an animated property transition using `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('div#target')
var startedAt, duration = 3000
var domain = [-100, window.innerWidth]
var range = domain[1] - domain[0]

function start() {
  startedAt = Date.now()
  updateTarget(0)
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function update() {
  let elapsedTime = Date.now() - startedAt

  // playback is a value between 0 and 1
  // being 0 the start of the animation and 1 its end
  let playback = elapsedTime / duration

  updateTarget(playback)
  
  if (playback > 0 && playback < 1) {
   // Queue the next frame
   requestAnimationFrame(update)
  } else {
   // Wait for a while and restart the animation
   setTimeout(start, duration/10)
  }
}

function updateTarget(playback) {
  // Uncomment the line below to reverse the animation
  // playback = 1 - playback

  // Update the target properties based on the playback position
  let position = domain[0] + (playback * range)
  target.style.left = position + 'px'
  target.style.top = position + 'px'
  target.style.transform = 'scale(' + playback * 3 + ')'
}

start()
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">...HERE WE GO</div>
```

---

#### For Background Tasks (non-UI related)

@UpTheCreek comment:

> Fine for presentation issues, but still
>   there are some things that you need to keep running.

If you have background tasks that *needs* to be precisely executed at given intervals, you can use [HTML5 Web Workers](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/25/using-html5-web-workers-to-have-background-computational-power/). Take a look at [Möhre's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/5927432#12522580) for more details...

#### CSS vs JS "animations"

This problem and [many others](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) could be avoided by using CSS transitions/animations instead of JavaScript based animations which adds a considerable overhead. I'd recommend this [**jQuery  plugin**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) that let's you take benefit from CSS transitions just like the `animate()` methods.

Comment: I tried this on FireFox 5 and 'setInterva'l still runs even when the tab is not in focus. My code in 'setInterval' slides a slidshow using 'animate()'. It looks like the animation is queued up by FireFox.  When I go back on the tab, FireFox pops the queue immediately one after the other resulting in a fast moving slideshow until the queue is empty.

Comment: @nthpixel would adding .stop (as per www's answer) help in tat situation (as each time it would be clearing the previous animations)

Comment: @gordatron - .stop doesn't help my situation. Same behavior. And I'm on FireFox 6.0.2 now. I wonder if it's the way jQuery implements .animate.

Comment: @cvsguimaraes - yes good point. Do you know of anything in the spec that guarantees web workers will run even when in a background tab?  I'm a tad worried that the browser vendors will arbitrarily decide to clamp these in the future too...

Comment: I would change the next-last line of the code to read `before = now;` to get the elapsed time since the *start* instead of the *end* of the previous call. This is usually what you want when animating things. As it is now, if an execution of the interval function takes 15ms, `elapsedTime` will give 35ms (instead of 50ms which is the interval) next time it is called (when the tab is active).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as the MDN docs state otherwise for rAF. Link here -> US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 94):

I ran into the same problem with audio fading and HTML5 player. It got stuck when tab became inactive.
So I found out a WebWorker is allowed to use intervals/timeouts without limitation. I use it to post "ticks" to the main javascript.

WebWorkers Code:

```
var fading = false;
var interval;
self.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    switch (e.data) {
        case 'start':
            if (!fading){
                fading = true;
                interval = setInterval(function(){
                    self.postMessage('tick');
                }, 50);
            }
            break;
        case 'stop':
            clearInterval(interval);
            fading = false;
            break;
    };
}, false);
```

Main Javascript:

```
var player = new Audio();
player.fader = new Worker('js/fader.js');
player.faderPosition = 0.0;
player.faderTargetVolume = 1.0;
player.faderCallback = function(){};
player.fadeTo = function(volume, func){
    console.log('fadeTo called');
    if (func) this.faderCallback = func;
    this.faderTargetVolume = volume;
    this.fader.postMessage('start');
}
player.fader.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    console.log('fader tick');
    if (player.faderTargetVolume > player.volume){
        player.faderPosition -= 0.02;
    } else {
        player.faderPosition += 0.02;
    }
    var newVolume = Math.pow(player.faderPosition - 1, 2);
    if (newVolume > 0.999){
        player.volume = newVolume = 1.0;
        player.fader.postMessage('stop');
        player.faderCallback();
    } else if (newVolume < 0.001) {
        player.volume = newVolume = 0.0;
        player.fader.postMessage('stop');
        player.faderCallback();
    } else {
        player.volume = newVolume;
    }
});
```

Comment: Neat! Now let's hope they won't "fix" this.

Comment: Great! This approach should be used when you exactly need timers to be working but not just to fix some animation issues!

Comment: I made a great metronome with this. Interesting that all of the most popular html5 drum machines don't use this method and instead use the inferior regular setTimeout. http://skyl.github.io/grimoire/fretboard-prototype.html - chrome or safari plays it the best, right now.

Comment: They will "fix" it if developer start abusing it. With rare exceptions, your app is not that important that it should be consuming resources in the background to provide some minimal improvement in the user experience.

Comment: @Gunchars You are absolutely right but wouldn't it be better if apps could ask for users' permission in this regard? If a user is willing to allow this to happen, then why not?

Answer (score 61):

There is a solution to use Web Workers (as mentioned before), because they run in separate process and are not slowed down

I've written a tiny script that can be used without changes to your code - it simply overrides functions setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval.

Just include it before all your code.

[more info here](http://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer)

Comment: I have tested it on a project including libraries that were using timers (so I couldn't implement workers myself). It worked like a charm. Thanks for this library

Comment: @ruslan-tushov just tried it on chrome 60 but it seems to not have effect at all... I am calling few functions from several setTimeout to add/remove elements to the DOM that are animated by css animations, and I see them freezed with some delay after tab switch (just as usual without plugins)

Comment: @neoDev Do you load the HackTimer.js (or HackTimer.min.js) before any other JavaScript?

Comment: @neoDev it sounds really strange, because I recently tried and it works

Comment: @DurdenP yes I tried also to put it before any other JavaScript. Maybe because I was using css animations? I remember also I tried webworkers but without luck

Comment: I've also tried this library from 2017 and it didn't work in Safari 12. I made sure to include it before all other scripts. Can someone please confirm if it still works?

Comment: @WindChimes I have tried the library in Chrome and it still works. Am not sure about Safari

Comment: I'm  a little confused - with React can  you just install this with NPM and you don't need to import anything?

Comment: Didn't work for me on Android Chrome when opening in private browser and switching to normal tab.

Answer (score 20):

Both `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` don't work when tab is inactive or work but not at the right periods. A solution is to use another source for time events. For example *web sockets* or *web workers* are two event sources that work fine while tab is inactive. So no need to move all of your code to a web worker, just use worker as a time event source:

```
// worker.js
setInterval(function() {
    postMessage('');
}, 1000 / 50);
```

.

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
var t1 = 0;
worker.onmessage = function() {
    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('fps =', 1000 / (t2 - t1) | 0);
    t1 = t2;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gowhari/pzywna6o/) of this sample.

Comment: " just use worker as a time event source" Thanks for the idea

Comment: The jsfiddle gives a SecurityError.

Answer (score 15):

For me it's not important to play audio in the background like for others here, my problem was that I had some animations and they acted like crazy when you were in other tabs and coming back to them. My solution was putting these animations inside **if** that is preventing **inactive tab**:

```
if (!document.hidden){ //your animation code here }
```

thanks to that my animation was running **only** if tab was active. 
I hope this will help someone with my case.

Comment: Amidst complex answers, this simple solution came to the rescue. Thank you.

Comment: Inactive tab is considered hidden?
I have a code that speaks every 5 minutes.
Sometimes it stops speaking.
It is not the code = it is Chrome - set to not discard - doesn't help...
I do use setTimeout - is this where I should use the "if (!document.hidden)"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Just do this:

```
var $div = $('div');
var a = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    a++;
    $div.stop(true,true).css("left", a);
}, 1000 / 30);
```

Inactive browser tabs buffer some of the `setInterval` or `setTimeout` functions.

`stop(true,true)` will stop all buffered events and execute immediatly only the last animation.

The `window.setTimeout()` method now clamps to send no more than one timeout per second in inactive tabs. In addition, it now clamps nested timeouts to the smallest value allowed by the HTML5 specification: 4 ms (instead of the 10 ms it used to clamp to).

Comment: This is good to know - for example for ajax updates where latest data is always correct - but for the question posted wouldn't this mean that the animation was significantly slowed / paused as "a" would not have been incremented the appropriate number of times?

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by Ruslan's answer, a handy little class you can just copy&paste into your code as a replacement for `setInterval`:

```
class WorkerInterval {
  worker = null;
  constructor(callback, interval) {
    const blob = new Blob([`setInterval(() => postMessage(0), ${interval});`]);
    const workerScript = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.worker = new Worker(workerScript);
    this.worker.onmessage = callback;
  }

  stop() {
    this.worker.terminate();
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
   const interval = new WorkerInterval(callback, 100);
   // sometime later
   interval.stop();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that a best understanding about this problem is in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TAHDb/

I am doing a simple thing here:

Have a interval of 1 sec and each time hide the first span and move it to last, and show the 2nd span.

If you stay on page it works as it is supposed. 
But if you hide the tab for some seconds, when you get back you will see a weired thing.

Its like all events that didn't ucur during the time you were inactive now will ocur all in 1 time. so for some few seconds you will get like X events. they are so quick that its possible to see all 6 spans at once.

So it seams chrome only delays the events, so when you get back all events will occur but all at once...

A pratical application were this ocur iss for a simple slideshow. Imagine the numbers being Images, and if user stay with tab hidden when he came back he will see all imgs floating, Totally mesed.

To fix this use the stop(true,true) like pimvdb told.
THis will clear the event queue.

Comment: In fact this is because of `requestAnimationFrame` that jQuery used. Because of some quirks it had (like this one), they removed it. In 1.7 you don't see this behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/TAHDb/1/. Because the interval is once per second this actually does not affect the issue I posted, as the maximum for inactive tabs is also once per second - so that makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I bring here a simple solution for anyone who is trying to get around this problem in a timer function, where as [@kbtzr mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927432/117259) we can use the Date object instead of fixed increments to calculate the time that has passed since the beginning, which will work even if you are out from the application's tab.

This is the example HTML.

```
<body>
  <p id="time"></p>
</body>
```

Then this JavaScript:

```
let display = document.querySelector('#time')
let interval
let time
function startTimer() {
    let initialTime = new Date().getTime()
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        let now = new Date().getTime()
        time = (now - initialTime) + 10
        display.innerText = `${Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000)) % 60)}:${Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60)}:${Math.floor((time / 10) % 100)}`
    }, 10)
}
startTimer()
```

That way, even if the interval value is increased for performance reasons of inactive tabs, the calculation made will guarantee the correct time. This is a vanilla code, but I used this logic in my React application, and you can modify it for wherever you need as well.

Answer (score 3):

Heavily influenced by Ruslan Tushov's library, I've created my own small [library](https://github.com/myonov/momentum). Just add the script in the `<head>` and it will patch `setInterval` and `setTimeout` with ones that use `WebWorker`.

Comment: just tried it on chrome 60 but it seems to not have effect at all... I am calling few functions from several setTimeout to add/remove elements to the DOM that are animated by css animations, and I see them freezed with some delay after tab switch (just as usual without plugins)

Comment: I use it with Chrome 60. Can you make a demo and post it on the github issues?

Answer (score 2):

Playing an audio file ensures full background Javascript performance for the time being

For me, it was the simplest and least intrusive solution - apart from playing a faint / almost-empty sound, there are no other potential side effects

You can find the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51191818/914546

(From other answers, I see that some people use different properties of the Audio tag, I do wonder whether it's possible to use the Audio tag for full performance, without actually playing something)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite old question but I encountered the same issue.

If you run your web on chrome, you could read through this post [Background Tabs in Chrome 57](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs).

Basically the interval timer could run if it haven't run out of the timer budget.

The consumption of budget is based on CPU time usage of the task inside timer.

Based on my scenario, I draw video to canvas and transport to WebRTC.

The webrtc video connection would keep updating even the tab is inactive.

However you have to use `setInterval` instead of `requestAnimationFrame` but itt is not recommended for UI rendering though.

It would be better to listen `visibilityChange` event and change render mechenism accordingly.

Besides, you could try what [Kaan Soral suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51192006/117259) and it should works based on the documentation.

Comment: but setInterval  not working if tab is inactive

Comment: @KapilSoni hey did you find any solution man, please comment..

Comment: @PawanDeore i have used rxjs interval(1000) instead of that

Answer (score 1):

I modified [Lacerda's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870907/1762224), by adding a functioning UI.

I added start/resume/pause/stop actions.

```js
const
  timer = document.querySelector('.timer'),
  timerDisplay = timer.querySelector('.timer-display'),
  toggleAction = timer.querySelector('[data-action="toggle"]'),
  stopAction = timer.querySelector('[data-action="stop"]'),
  tickRate = 10;
let intervalId, initialTime, pauseTime = 0;

const now = () => new Date().getTime();

const formatTime = (hours, minutes, seconds) =>
  [hours, minutes, seconds]
    .map(v => `${isNaN(v) ? 0 : v}`.padStart(2, '0'))
    .join(':');

const update = () => {
  let
    time = (now() - initialTime) + 10,
    hours = Math.floor((time / (60000)) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60),
    seconds = Math.floor((time / 10) % 100);
  timerDisplay.textContent = formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
};

const
  startTimer = () => {
    initialTime = now();
    intervalId = setInterval(update, tickRate);
  },
  resumeTimer = () => {
    initialTime = now() - (pauseTime - initialTime);
    intervalId = setInterval(update, tickRate);
  },
  pauseTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    pauseTime = now();
  },
  stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    initialTime = undefined;
    pauseTime = 0;
  },
  restartTimer = () => {
    stopTimer();
    startTimer();
  };

const setButtonState = (button, state, text) => {
  button.dataset.state = state;
  button.textContent = text;
};

const
  handleToggle = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.dataset.state) {
      case 'pause':
        setButtonState(e.target, 'resume', 'Resume');
        pauseTimer();
        break;
      case 'resume':
        setButtonState(e.target, 'pause', 'Pause');
        resumeTimer();
        break;
      default:
        setButtonState(e.target, 'pause', 'Pause');
        restartTimer();
    }
  },
  handleStop = (e) => {
    stopTimer();
    update();
    setButtonState(toggleAction, 'initial', 'Start');
  };

toggleAction.addEventListener('click', handleToggle);
stopAction.addEventListener('click', handleStop);
update();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
}

.timer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.timer .timer-display {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: #111;
  color: #8F8;
  border: thin solid #222;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.timer .timer-actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.timer .timer-actions button[data-action] {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 6em;
  border: thin solid #444;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.timer .timer-actions button[data-action]:hover {
  background: #444;
  border: thin solid #666;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="timer-display"></div>
  <div class="timer-actions">
    <button data-action="toggle" data-state="initial">Start</button>
    <button data-action="stop">Stop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This solution is not suitable if you like your interval works on the background, for example, playing audio or something else. But if you are confused for example about your animation not working properly when coming back to your page or tab, this is a good solution.

There are many ways to achieve this goal, maybe the "WebWorkers" is the most standard one **but** certainly, it's not the easiest and handy one, especially If you don't have enough Time, so you can try this way:

#### The basic concept:

1. build a name for your interval(or animation) and set your interval(animation), so it would run when user first time open your page : `var interval_id = setInterval(your_func, 3000);`
2. by `$(window).focus(function() {});` and `$(window).blur(function() {});` you can `clearInterval(interval_id)` everytime browser(tab) is deactived and ReRun your interval(animation) everytime browser(tab) would acive again by `interval_id = setInterval();`

#### Sample code:

```
var interval_id = setInterval(your_func, 3000);

$(window).focus(function() {
    interval_id = setInterval(your_func, 3000);
});
$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my rough solution

```
(function(){
var index = 1;
var intervals = {},
    timeouts = {};

function postMessageHandler(e) {
    window.postMessage('', "*");

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    sysFunc._each.call(timeouts, function(ind, obj) {
        var targetTime = obj[1];

        if (now >= targetTime) {
            obj[0]();
            delete timeouts[ind];
        }
    });
    sysFunc._each.call(intervals, function(ind, obj) {
        var startTime = obj[1];
        var func = obj[0];
        var ms = obj[2];

        if (now >= startTime + ms) {
            func();
            obj[1] = new Date().getTime();
        }
    });
}
window.addEventListener("message", postMessageHandler, true);
window.postMessage('', "*");

function _setTimeout(func, ms) {
    timeouts[index] = [func, new Date().getTime() + ms];
    return index++;
}

function _setInterval(func, ms) {
    intervals[index] = [func, new Date().getTime(), ms];
    return index++;
}

function _clearInterval(ind) {
    if (intervals[ind]) {
        delete intervals[ind]
    }
}
function _clearTimeout(ind) {
    if (timeouts[ind]) {
        delete timeouts[ind]
    }
}

var intervalIndex = _setInterval(function() {
    console.log('every 100ms');
}, 100);
_setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('run after 200ms');
}, 200);
_setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('closing the one that\'s 100ms');
    _clearInterval(intervalIndex)
}, 2000);

window._setTimeout = _setTimeout;
window._setInterval = _setInterval;
window._clearTimeout = _clearTimeout;
window._clearInterval = _clearInterval;
})();
```

Comment: The `postMessageHandler` invokes its own event it is handling, thereby having an infinite loop that is not blocking the UI. And while it is infinitely looping it is checking with each event-handling if there is a timeout or interval function to run.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to call my callback function at minimum of 250ms using audio tag and handling its ontimeupdate event. Its called 3-4 times in a second. Its better than one second lagging setTimeout

Answer (score -2):

There is a workaround for this problem, although actually the **tab must be made active in some window**.

- Make your inactive tab a separate browser window.
- Don't make any **other window maximized** (unless the maximized window is behind yours).

This should give the browser the impression of always being active.

This is bit cumbersome, but also a quick win. Provided one has control over windows arrangement.