# Indexeddb - Update record by index key

Tags: indexeddb

I have an object store with keypath "id" (autoincrement), and a unique index on that store with keypath "myId" that is generated from a server.
When I need to update a record, I won't have "id" available, so how can I update the record just by using "myId" considering that the index is unique?

I already tried using mystore.put(record), but that gives an error since a record with "myId" already exists.

Answer (score 6):

Since you've already got a unique key index on your `myId` property you can retrieve the record based on that value. You'll need to use the [`only`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBKeyRange-only-static-IDBKeyRange-any-value) `IDBKeyRange` and a `cursor` query, like so:

```
var transaction = db.transaction('myStore');
var store = transaction.objectStore('myStore');
var index = store.index('myId_Index');
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(obj.myId);

var request = index.openCursor(keyRange);

request.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var cursor = e.target.result;

    if (cursor) {
        var item = cursor.value;
        obj.id = item.id;
        //save the object
    }
};
```

Also, if you want to update using the same transaction you'll need to make it a `readwrite` not `readonly` as I did.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like exactly what I need. Follow-up question - I need to update many records in one transaction, would the method shown here be the best way - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13666741/1781631

Comment: If you have to update many records in one transaction then you might want to just walk the cursor using cursor.continue(nextMyId) instead of using a keyRange that specifies just one object.

Comment: @dgrogan - Can you provide an example of that? I do need to update many records at once.