# User idle time while typing in input

Tags: jquery, user-input, idle-timer

The problem I'm having is a search function which should call my `doSearch()`-method after the user stopped typing for at least 100ms in my `$("input#q)` field.

I tried to achieve this by using the logic of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029518/982002), but I'm stuck with where I should set/unset the `setInterval()` which increments the `idleTime`.

```
var idleTime = 0;

$("input#q").keyup(function() {
  idleTime = 0;
  idleInterval = setInterval(function() {
    idleTimeIncrement();
  }, 25);
});

function idleTimeIncrement() {
  idleTime += 25;
  if (idleTime >= 100) {
    doSearch($("input#q").val());
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting in Firebug Console says:

> Too much recursion.

So I guess I'm having an infinite loop in my code... ;-)

Comment: See the answer by Ianzz below, but just a word of advice - 100ms is a very short time.  You may want to increase it to more (about 500 works for me).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll check out 500ms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to reset your timer when you start a new one. Here's what I would do:

```
var timer = null;
$('input#q').keyup(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        doSearch($('input#q').val())
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: "keyup", all lowercase