# keyup(function()) ajax request delay - jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a jQuery Ajax request, that I want to call with text input, and so I nested it inside `keyup(function()`. This works fine.

```
$("#text_box").keyup(function() {
 //AJAX REQUEST
});
```

But this behaves buggy sometimes. When I input some text very fast, I am getting results for input word with some last letters of the original input word omitted (may be some fault with browser). I want the ajax request to be sent when there is no input activity for a second, I mean, if I input text very fast and rest for a second (means I made the input). How can I do this?

Comment: An almost identical question has actually been asked already _today_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830972/user-idle-time-while-typing-in-input

Comment: You can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds as if you get results from a previous ajax call. Use a timer with `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

```
var timer = null;

$("#text_box").keyup(function() {
  if(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = setTimeout(someFunction, someDelay);
});
```

Where `someFunction` is a function which does your ajax call and `someDelay` is the delay you want to wait before doing the call, after the user has typed, in ms.

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using jQuery you could use the [debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) plugin from Ben Aleman.

Example from the page

```
// Bind the not-at-all debounced handler to the keyup event.
  $('input.text').keyup( text_1 );

  // Bind the debounced handler to the keyup event.
  $('input.text').keyup( $.debounce( 250, text_2 ) ); // This is the line you want!
```

Answer (score 1):

omg. for somebody who will search in 2014...

```
function sendAjax() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "url.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
}

<input onkeyup="function()">
```