# Script to find the page idle time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-mobile

If a user is not performing any task on a page i.e the page is idle, is there any way to capture the time the page was idle or nothing was done on it. I am using JSP, struts1, JQM, JS in my project.

Comment: What do you mean by "doing something on it"?

Comment: A Page is Event Based, some an action triggers an Event. Are you saying that if there are no "Events" you want to log the "time". Or are you talking about no "server-side" postbacks?

Comment: check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Answer (score 1):

Idle time implementation using:

1. [YUI](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/02/detecting-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript-and-yui-3/)
2. [jQuery](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)
3. Or use the below script:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   idleTime = 0;

   $(document).ready(function () {
       //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
       var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 minute

       //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
       $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
           idleTime = 0;
       });

       $(this).keypress(function (e) {
           idleTime = 0;
       });
   })

   function timerIncrement() {
       idleTime = idleTime + 1;

       if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes
           window.location.reload();
       }
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Nice answer. But please quote the source if you copied pasted the answer from another answer on SO. Just a matter of courtesy. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Triggers onclick, [onmousemove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp) and [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) of the body-tag to get the current user action. After one of these has triggered you can set a timestamp and query the idle-time via setTimeout() or setIntervall(). You fetch the current timestamp and subtract the timestamp from the last action.