# Jquery Is user active on text field?

Tags: jquery, keypress

There is a lot of examples about keypress, keyup,... in jQuery. These examples are about typing in text field. When user type a message or something in text field we can display something like User is typing but we can't display a message about situation when user don't type. Here is an example from http://api.jquery.com/keypress/:

```
$("#target").keypress(function() {
  $("#other).html("User is typing");
});  

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="target" type="text" value="" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

How can I change this code and display message (user is not typing) when he don't type? Something like else option....

EDIT: Here is my idea. It is similar with yours idea (code). Thanks for helping.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#target").keyup(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $("#other").html("User is not typing");
      }, 2000);   
  });
  $("#target").keydown(function(){
    $("#other").html("User is typing");
  });
});
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/667555/944681)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using delay:

```
$("#target").keypress(function() {
      $("#other").html("User is typing");
      $("#other").delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("User is not typing");
        n();
    });  
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CbGL9/9/

Comment: A little optimized version:
`$("#other").html("User is typing").delay(1000).html("");`

Comment: Your code works properly. But I ask you: What will happen after one second. Answer: There will always be a message: "User is not typing".

Comment: well I noticed .delay doesnt work with .html. I made an example of how it will work with .queue