# How to capture all scrolling events on a page without attaching an onscroll handler to every single container

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, dom-events

Consider the following Web page:

```
 <html>
   <body onscroll="alert('body scroll event')">
     <div style='width:200px;height:200px;overflow:auto' onscroll="alert('div scroll event')">
       <div style='height:400px'>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

This html creates a div with a scrollbar. If you move the scrollbar, the `onscroll` event on the div element is triggered. However, the `onscroll` event on the body is NOT fired. This is expected, since the W3C states that element `onscroll` events do not "bubble".

However, I'm developing a client-side web framework that needs to know any time a scroll bar on ANY element of the page is scrolled. This would be easy to do if `onscroll` bubbled, but unfortunately it does not. Is there any other way to detect `onscroll` events across an entire page? (Right now I'm focusing mainly on Webkit, so a Webkit-specific solution would be fine...)

Here are some things I've tried:

1. Capturing `DOMAttrModified` (doesn't seem to fire for moving scrollbars.)
2. Using DOM Observers (also don't seem to fire for scrollbars)
3. Changing the `onscroll` event type to bubble (seems to not be possible)

It seems the ONLY way to capture `onscroll` events globally is to attach an `onscroll` event to EVERY element that may scroll, which is very ugly and is going to hurt the performance of my framework.

Anyone know a better way?

Comment: window.onscroll didn't work?

Answer (score 123):

The simplest way to detect all scroll events in modern browser would be using 'capturing' rather than 'bubbling' when attaching the event:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ code goes here }, true)
```

Unfortunately as I am aware there is no equivalent in older browser such as <= IE8

Comment: So much appreciation for this

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue.

The easiest way of course is to use jQuery. **Be aware that this method could potentially slow down your page *significantly*. Also it will not account for any new elements that are added after the event is bound.**

```
$("*").scroll(function(e) {
    // Handle scroll event
});
```

In vanilla JavaScript, you can set the `useCapture` boolean to `true` on your `addEventListener` call, and it will fire on all elements, including those added dynamically.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    // Handle scroll event
}, true);
```

Note though that this will fire before the scroll event actually happens.  As I understand it, there's two phases events go through.  The capture phase happens first, and starts from the page root (ownerDocument?) and traverses down to the element where the event happened.  After this comes the bubbling phase, which traverses from the element back up to the root.

Some quick testing too showed that this may be how jQuery handles it (for tracking scrolls on all page elements at least), but I'm not 100% sure.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the vanilla JavaScript method http://jsfiddle.net/0qpq8pcf/

Comment: Be careful with the first approach, because attaching event listeners to every single DOM element can make things VERY slow (not to mention that this does not account for elements added after creating the event handler).

The second is probably preferable, but you should also remove it whenever it's not needed, if possible (e.g. if you only want it to know when to dismiss a popup or something, only attach it while the popup is open and remove it when the popup closes).

Comment: I was trying to figure out which element was doing the scrolling (and hence to attach a scroll handler to after it broke with a CSS change) and the first method wasn't giving me anything.  Turns out, it was the `document` itself, so previously the handler was attached the "body" and that stopped working.  The 2nd method helped me find that it was indeed the document/window itself that was scrolling.

Answer (score 10):

**...crickets chirping...* *

OK, I guess this question isn't going to get any stackoverflow love, so I might as well answer my own question as to the best solution I've found so far, in case another user stumbles across this question:

The best solution I've come up with is to capture "onmousedown" and "onkeydown" for the BODY element: These events bubble, and so if a user tries to move a scrollbar on the page these global functions will fire as a by-product. Then, in these functions, simply look up event.target and attach a temporary "onscroll" event to those objects until the mouse/key is "up" again. Using that method, you can avoid "handler bloat" and still globally capture all "onscroll" events. (I think this will work for "mouse wheel" scrolling as well, but my research on that final wrinkle is still pending.)

Comment: Also you should add a mousewheel event to document.

Comment: nice - I didn't event get into the entire answer but as soon as you mentioned "onmousedown" I was already pointed to the right direction - thank you

Comment: `mousedown` does not seem to get activated if you touch the screen with two fingers, then scroll and then lift them from the screen. So it won't necessarily precede every window scroll action. I tried on a mac inside a firefox tab.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine when you want to i.e. close a dialog after anything in the background is scrolled:

```
var scrollListener = function(e) {
    // TODO: hide dialog
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener, true);
};

document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to handle scrolling in any context in a complex of custom elements with scroll events in shadowRoots. This covers at least part of the problem in my scenario and generally borrows from the answers and comments here in the context of these newer web component APIs. Attaching and detaching the listener in the appropriate lifecycle callbacks works well so-far (once might not fit your use-case).

```
      self.addEventListener('mousewheel', handler, {capture: true, once: true});
      self.addEventListener('keydown', handler, {capture: true, once: true});
```

Note too the `event.composedPath()` provides the entire event path through all the shadowRoots with all the nodes if specifics about the scrolling context are needed. If this is the case it might make sense to use this approach and attach a new handler for that specific scenario--to the node of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Like drcode said, capture on body tag is the trick. I just add touchmove to work on mobile.

```
 document
      .querySelector("body")
      .addEventListener("mousewheel", e => {
        console.log("scroll");
      });

    document
      .querySelector("body")
      .addEventListener("touchmove", e => {
        console.log("scroll");
      });
```

Regards,