# Capture all scroll events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Is there a way to capture all the scrolling events on any elements in the DOM? In a similar way to `MutationObserver` which tells you about general DOM changes, is there a way to hear about general scroll events (in a roughly cross-browser compliant way)?

Obviously, ideally I don't want to try and attach listeners for scrolling to every element in the DOM manually (both because of the hassle of doing so and the fear that my browser would explode).

Alternatively, I'd be good with a way to detect all DOM elements that currently have visible scrollbars (such that I could then isolate those elements and attach scroll listeners only to them) but I imagine this to be no less complicated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture all scrolling events on a page without attaching an onscroll handler to every single container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184779/how-to-capture-all-scrolling-events-on-a-page-without-attaching-an-onscroll-hand)

Comment: the scroll event does not bubble, so you have to attach an event handler to every element that has a scrollbar

Comment: @G.Mendes good catch, did not spot that.

Comment: @Ryven a way around could be adding a specific `class` to all DOM elements that are possible to `overflow` and then attach the event to that class but still won't work to elements created after it was attached

Comment: an adjusted answer for custom elements with shadowRoots includes general approach for finding specific scrolling nodes to handle directly and dynamically at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69958607/965666

Comment: Maybe there is an even more performant way of doing what you are trying to achieve… So, what are you trying to achieve? (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("*").on("scroll",function(event){
 // Your code to handle

});
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: only downside is that this could potentially do a LOT of work