# insert data after certain time in a page

Tags: php, mysql, time

i coded this :

```
<?php
include("includes/config.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
{


if(is_numeric($_GET['num']) && mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])){
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$video_id=$_GET['id'];
$video_num=$_GET['num'];
$checknum=mysql_query("select visitedpage.video_id,visitedpage.video_num from visitedpage where video_num='$video_num'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($checknum);

if($num < 1){   
$savepage=mysql_query("insert into visitedpage(username,video_id,video_num) values ('$username','$video_id','$video_num')");
}

if($num < 1 ){
    $get=mysql_query("select users.percent from users where username='$username'");
    $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
    $now=$fetch['percent'];
    $add=1;
    $sum=$now + $add;
    $update=mysql_query("update users set percent='$sum' where username='$username'");
}

}}

?>
```

i want the code to be executed when user still in the page for about 10 minutes

i tried (sleep()) but this will stop the execution the rest of the page,
i need only this snippet to be delayed from execution ......

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why don't you create session and create a time stamp of 10 minutes?

Comment: an easy option would be to check the time as you navigate between pages. Set the variable when you log in to something like $_SESSION['sessiontime'] = time();. Then every time you change pages see if that original time is less than ten minutes from now.

Comment: drewdin,i'll tried to code your idea,and hope to code it in a right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you do an ajax request to this block of code after 10 minutes?
something like this. ...

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do the ajax after 10 seconds. 
}, 10000);
```

see this [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)
and this http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/

Answer (score 1):

You must do this with client side scripting (Javascript). You cannot have a server side script edit something already displayed on the client's browser after the fact.

Comment: thanks bro,but can u help meto code something like that via js

Comment: @mohamedamin Move that PHP script to another file, then after 10 minutes, have the web page exectute an AJAX request to said script. Append the result of the AJAX request to the page DOM. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You would likely need to use javascript to do what you want to do, as once your render the page source and send it to the browser, PHP no longer in use at all (until the next request from the client browser).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a javascript based solution with cookies and then do a AJAX-request.