# Next step after X seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

Is it possible to "auto" next step after X seconds in asp.net wizard? It has specified time for answering question.

Comment: "It's specified time for answering question." what does this mean..?

Comment: I;m using wizard for a quiz. User has X seconds for answering one question. After X seconds wizard must go to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use a client-side script to start a timer on page load and then to  redirect the page after a set amount of time if no keypress or mousemovement is detected. Take a look at Javascript's [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function for the timing part. And the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029518/287254) for the part that detects user activity.