# Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) vs not

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, anonymous-function, iife

I see a lot of code like:

```
var myApp ={};
(function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    this.var1 = "mark";     //"this" is global, because it runs immediately on load.  Caller is global
    myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
        console.log("Goodbye");
    };
})();
```

Which causes the anonymous function to execute immediately.  But what is the advantage of this, compared to just putting the code inline?

```
var myApp ={};
console.log("Hello");
var1 = "mark";     
myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
    console.log("Goodbye");
};
```

Apparently it's to do with scope of the function, but as the function is anonymous and called by window, it's scope (i.e. `this`) is global, no?

Comment: in the second snippet , var1 is attached to window scope, in the first it is not.

Comment: But when I step through example 1 with Chrome, `var1` is global.

Comment: The reason for this structure isn't in the code we see. Or it's totally useless. Please show us more code.

Comment: I think the latter doesn't work in strict mode

Comment: @dystroy - This is an example, there is no other code.  According to Chrome, `var1` is global each time.

Comment: This code doesn't even make sense per se as var1 isn't used. So it's hard to tell why you would have used this construct.

Comment: anonymous functions dont change the value of `this` so in the first example youre doing `window.var1 = "mark"`

Comment: @VeXii - I realise that (I even put in in the comment in the code!).  My question is why people wrap code in anon functions, when it adds  complexity.  I must have missed something, because there seems to be no advantage to me, but it's the recommended method.  Hence the question - why is example 1 better than 2?

Comment: Simply : It's not better. This example makes no sense without context.

Comment: well if you where to use variables insted of adding to the global object, you can scoope. but the exampels like this dont make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you would have this :

```
        var myApp ={};
        (function() {
            console.log("Hello");
            var var1 = "mark";  
            myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
                console.log("Goodbye");
            };
        })();
```

The main difference is that `var1` doesn't clutter the global namespace. After this call, `var1` is still the same than before (generally undefined).

As `var1` can only be accessed from the function defineds in the closure, it is said "private".

Apart avoiding possible causes of conflicts, it's just cleaner not to keep global variables when useless.

Here, you don't have a local variable but a global one defined as `this.var1`. It's probably a bug, or the reason would be found elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the closest explanation.  As long as you `var` declare variables within the anon fn, they don't leak out to the global namespace.  I find the definition of `this` in javascript very confusing!

Answer (score 3):

One reason: wrapping your code in an anonymous function allows you to create a module which distinguishes a public API from private functions and variables that are only used internally to the module. This avoids polluting the global namespace.

```
var myApp ={};
(function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    this.var1 = "mark";

    function helper() {/*Some code here*/;}

    myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
        helper()
        console.log("Goodbye");
    };
})();
```

I could say:

```
var myApp ={};
console.log("Hello");
var var1 = "mark";

function helper() {/*Some code here*/;}

myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
    helper()
    console.log("Goodbye");
};
```

But then the global scope includes a function called `helper` which is of no use to anyone using your module, and could lead to possible naming conflicts with other modules.

I could alternatively just include `helper` as a method of myApp.

```
var myApp ={};
console.log("Hello");
var var1 = "mark";

myApp.helper = function() {/*Some code here*/;}

myApp.sayGoodbye = function() {
    this.helper()
    console.log("Goodbye");
};
```

However, I may wish to prevent users from directly calling `helper`, in which case this won't do.