# What is the default Django session lifetime and how to change it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, default, django-sessions

I can't find a setting for the default session lifetime in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/.

I know this can be changed manually ([How to expire Django session in 5minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830669/how-to-expire-django-session-in-5minutes)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age), the default value is `1209600` which is two weeks, in seconds.

Comment: "Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
The age of session cookies, in seconds."

But this for session cookies not the session itself, right?

Comment: When the cookie expires, so does the session, in facts the `session.set_expiry` used in the answer you mention sets the session cookie expiry.

Comment: @aumo, so if the user either deletes cookies or doesn't accept them, then the session is canceled?

Comment: @AlxVallejo the session remains stored server side but if the user's browser does not send the session cookie his requests do not get associated with the session

Answer (score 1):

You can change **the default Django session lifetime** by setting [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) to **"settings.py"** as shown below. By default, [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) is **1209600 seconds(2 weeks)**:

```py
# "settings.py"

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 180 # 3 minutes
```

> [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age)
>
> Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
>
> The age of session cookies, in seconds.