# Django - Refreshing sessions the easy way

Tags: python, django, templates, session

I have a question about refreshing sessions!
When I was making sessions expire using PHP I just required sessionmaintenance.php at the top of a document, is there an easy way to do the same in a Django template, so that I don't have to do it in every view?

Example view-code:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(30)
    testvar="Hi!"
    return render(request, 'testapp/index.html', {'testvar':testvar})

@login_required
def uploadview(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(30)
    etc...
```

What I'd like to do is make a base.html that looks something like this - Example template code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h6>{{ request.user.username }} {{ request.user.first_name }}</h6>
{% endif %}
{% request.session.set_expiry(30) %} 
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Incorporating the session refresh into my base.html so that my view-code looks cleaner and I don't have to repeat myself as much.

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing you should do in a template; those are fur presenting data to the user. You might consider a custom middleware, for example.

Comment: Of course you're right, I'm a bit new to Django still trying to get into best-practice, I'll look into middleware!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830669/how-to-expire-django-session-in-5minutes), definitely you will find what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but have you checked out the
[SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) parameter that's available for Django settings?

It sets the hard limit of session cookie in seconds, like so:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 30
```

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).