# Expiring a Django session at a specific time for a specific user (eg when their shift ends) at login

Tags: django, session, django-authentication, django-sessions

I have a system that has overlapping shift workers on it 24/7. Currently it is not uncommon for one to forget to log out and the next worker pick up their session and run with it. This causes some accountability issues.

I do realise there are options for session length ie `settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` but these are a bit blunt for our purposes. We have different workers with different shift lengths, managers who have 2FA on-action and it's basically just not the path we want to pursue. Simply put...

**I want to programmatically set the session death time on login.**

We already have a custom Login view but this bubbles up through the built-in django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm. And even there I can't see how to set an expiry on a particular session.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: `request.session`'s `.get_expiry_age()` and `set_expiry(value)` seem relevant *but* they do appear to update because they cycle around based on when the session was last modified, not when the session started. I need something that sets a maximum age on the session.

**Edit 2**: I guess I could write *into* the session on login and run something externally (a cronned management whatsit) that checked the expiries (if existed) and nuked each session that lapsed.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this by setting an expiry when the user logs on, because the session middleware will [update the expiry time](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7d49ad76562e8c0597a0eb66046ab423b12888d8/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L54) whenever a request causes the session to be saved. You could write a custom middleware (or subclass session middleware) to log out users when their shift ends.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831237/4186008?

Comment: @AmanGarg I had not. That does look like a similar solution to my last edit and Alasdair's comment. Looks like middleware is the right route out. Allows me to send the user a little message at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with an answer thanks to the comments. On login I insert the timestamp into session:

```
request.session['login_timestamp'] = timezone.now().timestamp()
```

If you're wondering why timestamp, and not `datetime.datetime.now()` or `timezone.now()`, Django's default session encoder uses JSON and Django's JSON encoder does not handle datetimes. This is circumventable by writing an encoder that can handle datetimes... But just using an integer seconds-since-epoch value is enough for me.

And then have a little middleware to check that session against the current time.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class MyMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # other checks to make sure this middleware should run.
        # eg, this only happens on authenticated URLs

        login_timestamp_ago = timezone.now().timestamp() - request.session.get('login_timestamp', timezone.now().timestamp())

        if settings.RECEPTION_LOGIN_DURATION and <insert user checks here> and login_timestamp_ago >= settings.RECEPTION_LOGIN_DURATION:
            logout(request)  # nukes session
            messages.warning(request, "Your session has expired. We need you to log in again to confirm your identity.")
            return redirect(request.get_full_path())
```

The order of events here is quite important. `logout(request)` destroys the whole session. If you write a message (stored in session) beforehand, it'll be missing after the `logout(request)`.