# Django session: disconnect when user is inactive

Tags: django, authentication, disconnect, user-inactivity

is there a simple way to disconnect a user that is inactive for 3 minutes for example?

I have develop an authentification app following a tutorial (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60GTvKCuam8&list=PLLxk3TkuAYnryu1lEcFaBr358IynT7l7H

I use 'from django.contrib.auth import views'

so I did not have write the login/logout/... views and have the default authentification behavior

here I need to customize the behavior so I suppose I need to override the logout view?
How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expire Django session in 5minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830669/how-to-expire-django-session-in-5minutes)

Comment: I never write a middleware but I will learn about it ; )