# How to expire a session in django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

There are some things i do not understand and i am not using in django, Like Serialize.
From another question :[How to expire Session in 5 mins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830669/how-to-expire-django-session-in-5minutes) The sessions is confusing me.The sessions are active added in my installed apps and middle ware but..
I am using a simple login from the URL like this :
 `path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),`

It generates a login form and work. How can i keep using this and now set Session expire time dynamically bases on user request to

> Remember Me

Or what should i change and start over again to implement this whole idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Please study the below link:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

   and use:

   set_expiry(value)