# How to detect page is not in use for more 10 min?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I want to set session as unlimitted by refreshing page every 10mins.

So i have to know page is using or not using right now ?

My refreshing code is working fine:

```
 string _CurUrl = Request.RawUrl.ToString();
 Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "600; URL=" + _CurUrl  + "");
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current refreshing code?

Comment: Q is: How to detect page is using or not using right now ?

Comment: You could listen to the javascript events for `keyUp` and `mouseMove` to track the time, if you want to check if a user is active on the site

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various jQuery plugins for detecting if a user is idle.

[jQuery idleTimer plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) - Paul Irish ([Code on GitHub](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/))

[jQuery Idle Timeout Plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/) - Eric Hynds ([Code on GitHub](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout))

[Auto Timeout Plugin](http://philpalmieri.com/2009/09/jquery-session-auto-timeout-with-prompt/) - Philip Almieri ([Code on GitHub](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout))

[Google Search Results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery%20page%20timeout&aq=f&oq=jquery%20page%20timeout&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l3.7912&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20idle%20timeout%20plugin&oq=jquery%20idle%20timeout%20plugin&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.4057.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..7.psy-ab.fvsLvIz5EY4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44011176,d.d2k&fp=bd1126af0f726197&biw=1440&bih=815) for more solutions.

I would use one of these rather than try to code something yourself which already exists. You will however have to customise the event which occurs when the TimeOut is detected to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should track keyPress and mouseMove events as  nunespascal suggested-

Here is the link. This might help you

http://forums.asp.net/t/1312010.aspx