# How to detect idle user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a  Web api in which I want to check that whether the client is inactive for 30 minutes. if it is so the user will be logged out automatically. I have no idea how to perform it. Please help

Comment: dupicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519100/how-to-detect-page-is-not-in-use-for-more-10-min)

Comment: Are you looking for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: GetLastInputInfo function works for only desktop application. My application is not desktop application

Comment: I want to check from server side that whether the user is active or not. my Application is a mvc4 web service.