# Log out automatically when there is no use of Keyboard or Mouse

Tags: php

When i do not use keyboard and mouse for a particular time limit (Like 10 min or 20 min) at that time it should log out User automatically from the current session. Please give me any suggestion or code in PHP.

Comment: Please describe how your login system works. With cookies?

Comment: Probably you are looking for this solution:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966686/auto-redirect-after-no-user-action][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966686/auto-redirect-after-no-user-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript to detect browser events.

With jQuery, something like (untested)

```
var timeSinceLastMove = 0;

$(document).mousemove(function() {

    timeSinceLastMove = 0;
});

$(document).keyup(function() {

    timeSinceLastMove = 0;
});

checkTime();

function checkTime() {

    timeSinceLastMove++;

    if (timeSinceLastMove > 10 * 60) {

        window.location = "path/to/logout.php";
    }

    setTimeout(checkTime, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set the session timeout in your code

session_set_cookie_params(3600); // sessions last 1 hour 
session_start(); // do this after setting the params