# jQuery: How to detect when mouse is static

Tags: jquery, mouse

I am working on jQuery and I need to detect when the mouse is static for more than 2 sec for example and then detect if it moves again. I maybe don't have the good name for that so I haven't found anything on google.
Thanks !

Comment: Please provide some evidence that you researched the topic. [A query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly) on SO would have yielded your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As kgdesouz pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077311/jquery-how-to-detect-when-mouse-is-static#comment24698813_17077311), [here is a simple script using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly) that handles `mousemove` and `keypress` events. If the time expires, the page is reloaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
})
function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
```