# How to know if the user is idle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically I want to run some code in jquery after the user has stopped doing anything in the browser like click,scroll. How to know if all functions have finished and jquery is not being busy (being run or used)

Basically run code only when the user is idle

Comment: you meant you want to know that page / user is ideal ?

Comment: @CodingAnt Yes right when page/user is ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting you right, this is what you were looking for

```
<script>
   $(function(){
     (function(seconds) {
     var refresh,       
      intvrefresh = function() {
      clearInterval(refresh);
      refresh = setTimeout(function() {
         alert('No activity from user 10 seconds, put your code here !');
       }, seconds * 1000);
      };
     $(document).on('click keydown keyup mousemove', function() { intvrefresh() });
                    intvrefresh();
      }(10));  
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: change it to ('click keydown keyup mousemove scroll')

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd wait until everything has loaded. This means that all elements have finished loading on the page (e.g. Images loaded in). There's nothing here to tell you that there's no JavaScript running in the background though.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: does .load run when the page has loaded and then user then scrolls and stops?

Comment: basically run code when user is idle.load will be when the page has finished loading

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
       var str =$('body').html();
    } catch ( e ) {
       alert('jquery not used');
    }
```

Do something like this. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moyeen52/EbWvq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I just answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419410/1137982). See if it makes sense.

TLDR;

You can do it more elegantly with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) and [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)-

```
$('body').on("click mousemove keyup", _.debounce(function(){
    // your code here.
}, 1200000)) // 20 minutes debounce
```