# How to notify the server when the user leaves page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application that needs to notify the server when a user leaves. To do so, I make an Ajax call posting a string to the server.

Currently, I'm making the call on the window.onbeforeunload event, but to do more than show the user a message, this event is very unreliable.

The other ways I come up to do this was by using SignalR to do a ping-pong request or to control something (session?) on the server side.

What's the best approach to make the server know when a user leave the application?

Comment: If I leave the browser open, but lock my computer and go grab a beer, do you consider me as having left your application?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson yes. After some time I consider that he has left the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an aproach for detecting iddle time in a page 
[Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly). And to detect disconnection I suggest you use handsaking approach (that can be used with signalR as you pointed out): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN-ACK#Connection_establishment