# Spring no change expire time in session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a method in controller, Is it possible to run this method without interference to session expire time ?
I'm checking something by ajax request every 5min, but in this case session never expire.
Session expire time is 30min.
In future I will be able to use websockets, but now I need solution in easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can track user's idle time with JQuery via some timer, then send ajax request to expire session.
[Detect user idle time with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)