# Load next page every minute - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a asp.net / C# site with multiple pages in an specific order. If there is no user interaction (mouse movement or keypresss) on the page for 1 min, the user should be redirected to the next page (I allready know the url from the next page).

What's the best way to accomplish that? Thnx in advance.

**EDIT:**

So far I have some code that was written by someone else in C# / VB:

```
    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", string.Format("{0}; url={1}", DisplayDuration.ToString(), NextPage));
```

The display duration is defined in a DB.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: _Well_, your question seems way broad. Any effort so far? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: Added code. I believe it isn't easy to implement this feature in the current code, this is why I wanna take a completley new approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly/24989958#24989958)

Rephrasing it for your scenario.

```
function CheckIfIdle() 
{
    var t;

  // Events to reset the timer
    window.onload = resetTimer;     
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer; 
    window.onclick = resetTimer;    
    window.onscroll = resetTimer;  
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function LoadNextPage() {
      //Here is where you have to provide the url or write your action when the user is idle
       window.location.href = 'Your next page url';
    }

    function resetTimer() {
      clearTimeout(t);
     // time is in milliseconds, please change the time accordingly
      t = setTimeout(LoadNextPage, 10000);  
    }
 }
```

Call the method `CheckIfIdle` in body `onLoad` to start listening.

Credits : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly/24989958#24989958)

Comment: Please tell me, why I am down voted. So that I can avoid it next time.

Comment: Code without any explanations does not a good answer make, especially when the question is that broad.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Edited. Will that be Ok?

Comment: @Shadow The script works fine for me, thanks :)

Comment: @Shadow, it is better. Of course, you still have ripped the source material verbatim from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24989958/464709), but that's between you, your conscience and the moderation team.

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score -1):

From the Question I am guessing that If a User is Idle for **1 Min** he will be redirected to some page you can use `JavaScript` for this purpose like

```
var seconds = 50
var minutes = 0
function display() {
   if (seconds <= 0) {
       minutes -= 1
       seconds = 59
    }
    if (minutes < 0) {
       window.location = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageName.aspx?")%>';
        }
    else {
       seconds -= 1
       if (seconds <= 10 && seconds>8) {
           var conf = confirm("Your Session is going to expire!");
           if (conf == true) {
               window.location = window.location.pathname;
           }
           else {
                window.location = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageName.aspx")%>';
            }
        }
document.getElementById('<%=lblsessiontime.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "Session expires in : " + minutes + "." + ("0" + seconds).slice(-2)
setTimeout("display()", 1000)
 }
```

}

Using the above `Javascript` a label in the Page will be used to display 
Session Time ticking in seconds(1 Min) like shown in the below Picture(in Picture the Session timing is 8 Minutes) if it reaches 0 then the User will be redirected to the page we have specified in the Code.

[image: Session Timing]

Comment: @Downvoter If you down vote my posting kindly mention the reason why you have down voted it I will try to rectify it from Next time.