# Having trouble making my Chrome Extension run idle in the background

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension that one click on it's icon in the toolbar turns it on and then afterwards it runs in the background. When pages go idle for a certain amount of time, the screen blurs out and changes colors. I've got the actual blurring and changing colors working but as of right now when a user clicks on the button, it only works when on the active tab instead of just running in the background. I've also tested out using Chrome's Idle API but nothing

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 var timeoutID;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
 }

setup();

function startTimer() {
   // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
   timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
   window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);

goActive();
}

function goInactive() {


 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "inject.js"});

 }



 });
```

This is my Manifest Background and Permission.

```
 "background": {
   "scripts": ["event.js"],
   "persistent": false
 }

  "permissions": [
   "tabs",
    "*://*/*",
    "idle"
]
```

Comment: Oh-oh, see the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). The background page doesn't generate any mouse events, it's a hidden page of the extension that runs its background scripts.

Comment: So would it be better as a content script?

Comment: Well, if you want it to work then of course. I don't see any other way for [Detecting idle time in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/667555)