# Show Popup after 10min of inactive

Tags: javascript, time, popup

**Hello**,
can't find a code :x Can someone post, or explain how can i make a Popup after 10minutes of inactive ?

When member is inactive of 10minutes after Page is loaded, the members will get a Popup with some Buttons and Text

```
<div>
    <p>Away from keyboard?</p>
    <ul class="button">
        <li><a href="#0">I'm Back!</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps try the solution provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Answer (score 1):

```
 var seconds = 0;
        var timeoutCounter = setInterval(function(){
        seconds++;
        if(sec == 600) {
    // do stuff to launch popup
    clearInterval(timeoutCounter);
    }
        }, 1000);


    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
clearInterval(timeoutCounter);
        seconds = 0;
    setInterval(timeoutCounter);
        });
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            clearInterval(timeoutCounter);
            seconds = 0;
    setInterval(timeoutCounter);
        });
```

This basically runs every second - and if it's the 600th second, it quits after running your code.

[Source for idle checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Comment: You don't check if the user is idle or not. You have to monitor mouse / keyboard.

Comment: @Ilya The person who owns the page should be able to set seconds = 0, when the user makes a meaningful interaction.  Sometimes you don't want to do that too generically.

Comment: This is not working for what the OP is asking for  'after 10 minutes of inactive '  so I suggest you to let the OP know that or to update your answer with a note.

Comment: @Ilya and Franco you're absolutely right. Added the idle checker.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the events to the `document` object along with the `setTimeout` method to display the popup. One way to do it is

```
var popupTimer,
        TIME_OUT = 600;

// function that displays the popup
function displayPopup() {
    // display the popup here
}

// Set the timeout to display the popup
popupTimer = setTimeout(displayPopup, TIME_OUT);

// attch events to the document object
// you can add more events here based on
// what events you want to track
$(document).on('click change keypress', function() {

  // clear the timeout whenever the event is handled
  clearTimeout(popupTimer);

  // Reset the timer
  popupTimer = setTimeout(displayPopup, TIME_OUT);
});
```