# Is there a JQuery or Javascript warning message utility which shows and timeouts without interfering with the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, utility

I am looking for some non-modal warning messages which would stack on the right side of the screen and not interfere with the user working on the screen. I have forgotten that little utility name and where I can download it from.

Any help would be very appreciated...

DK

Comment: Very mature. Regardless of your personal feelings, [requests to find libraries for you are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Literally the first Google result when searching for "js stacking notifications" is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Please check the link. There are a bunch of suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: @DeKoss At what point did I unload on you? I just said to google it. It's not my fault if you had a case of [tip-of-the-tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_of_the_tongue). Maybe don't insult people and their significant others (my girlfriend is a lovely lady) and maybe you'll get nicer responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these should suit your requirements:
[notification plugins](http://jqueryhouse.com/best-jquery-notification-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks @DenizEng.  Looks good too...