# Put website in foreground after 10 minutes of inactivity

Tags: jquery, html, focus, foreground

I have created something similar to a platform. It is a HTML site and shown on a touch display. I want the site to focus after 10 minutes of inactivity. So the site is in the foreground. I tried:

```
$window.focus(function() {
    self.focus();
    window.setTimeout("focus()",600000);
});
```

But it doesn't work. Has anybody a working solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: You cannot do this as JS does not have low level access to the OS to force a window to focus.

Comment: And how can I force the window to focus?