# How to dismiss bootstrap modal if no action in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to dismiss bootstrap modal if no action in browser screen for 10-15 seconds.

I have tried settimeout() function but this will not check the action in the browser.

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#form').modal('hide');}, 10000);
```

So, Is there any way to hide modal box if no action in the browser?

Comment: `clearTimeout` if there is any action...

Comment: What kind of action you expect? Click/mousemove/keypress?

Comment: yeah any action in browser like click/touch/tap etc

Comment: you are reffering to idle user state for 10-15 second. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below with set the flag `actionAppeared` if there a `keypress` in the keyboard or 'mousemove' in the mouse.

```
var actionAppeared = false;

jQuery(document).mousemove(function (e) { actionAppeared = true; });
jQuery(document).keypress(function (e) { actionAppeared = true; });

setTimeout(function() {
    if(!actionAppeared) {
        $('#form').modal('hide');}
    }
, 10000);
```

Here is a working [demo](http://www.bootply.com/6W2OlggdNV). Open the console to see the `mousemove` and `keypress` events.

The `mousemove` events is triggered really easy so to test it open the modal and quickly move the cursor away from the keyboard.

Comment: But this is specific to event only.

Comment: @BhumiShah what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean your demo is not working when mouse is over the popup or working only once.I am not sure but it is not working everytime.

Comment: I updated the link with a new one, only a few minutes after I posted the first. Maybe you were looking at the first link. Do you mind taking a look again?

Comment: modal shown and then mousemove is not dismiss the modal

Comment: Maybe this http://www.bootply.com/Ix30T9Xa15? In this demo, only `keypress` and `mousedown` (e.g. a mouse click) cancels the auto dismiss of the modal.