# Auto Logout When User Inactive Node.js

Tags: javascript, logout

I have problem with auto logout when the user is inactive.
I have a logout button and a redirect homepage "/"

app.js

```
app.get('/logout',userContro.user_logout);
```

userController.js

```
user_logout = function(req,res){
   res.clearCookie("userId"); //clear cookie
   res.redirect('/'); 
};
```

What I need is to redirect to the homepage when the user is inactive for 5 minutes.
I can try using `setInterval` when the user `logIn` and counter and then return `true` if timeout, but I don't know how to add the function to redirect to the homepage.

I found [Session auto logout after inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143993/session-auto-logout-after-inactivity) but it is still not working for me.

Thanks, everyone so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using the session library of npm will work on this situation.

Install it using the following command.

`npm install express-session`

Then, require it and use it in the app.js as follow

```
var session=require('express-session')
app.use(session({secret:"Key",cookie:{maxAge:600000}}))
```

Here, the maxAge is a property that automatically session out when there is no request come from the user within the specified time.

Comment: Do we had to validate in the client side if the cookie exists? to keep the user logged in or log him out

Answer (score 0):

I done with handling in file js fontend:

```
setInterval(check_Mouse,1000); //check every second
var x=0;
var cnt=0;
function myFunction(e) {
    cnt=0;      //onmousemove
}
function check_Mouse(){
if(cnt==120){   //number second to logout
    cnt=0;
    window.location.href="/";   //go to homepage
}else{
    cnt+=1;   //if not timeout, cnt++
}
}
```