# Automatically trigger click function javascript

Tags: jquery, html

Novice web designer, need special help.

I have an html5 audio player that starts to play once a site visitor clicks the 'play' button.  I would like for the click function to occur automatically if a site visitor remains idle on the website for more than 5 seconds.  Any suggestions or direction on this would be very helpful.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {



$('.spinner-wrap').click(function() {



var $this = $(this),
    audio = $this.siblings('audio')[0],
    bpm = Number($this.siblings('audio').data('bpm'))
    pulse = (60/bpm)*1000;



if (audio.paused === false) {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  $this.removeClass('playing');
  clearInterval(intervals);
}

else {
  audio.play();
  $this.addClass('playing');

}




function pulsing() {

  $this.addClass('pulse');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeClass('pulse');  
  }, pulse-100);

}


  });

});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with java...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Comment: Suggestion: I think 5 seconds is too much time for being idle, just auto-play with mute within a second of loading.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed.  However, there is an animation that needs to auto-play/auto-start as well along with the audio.  Is there a simple way to do this?