# Electron App -How to automatically log out a user after inactivity for 15 minutes?

Tags: javascript, timeout, desktop-application, logout, electron

I am making an electron app and wonder how I can automatically log out the user after being inactive for lets say 15 minutes! Thanks a lot!

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

let willQuitApp = false;
let window;

app.on('ready', () => {
  window = new electron.BrowserWindow();

  window.on('close', (e) => {
    if (willQuitApp) {
    window = null;
   } else {
      /* the user only tried to close the window */
    e.preventDefault();
    window.hide();
   }
  });

  window.loadURL(`mypage`); /* load your page */

});
app.on('activate', () => window.show());

app.on('before-quit', () => willQuitApp = true);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in idle time in your app specifically then this has been [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly). On the other hand if you're interested in system idle time then you'll want to use https://github.com/paulcbetts/node-system-idle-time

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Electron Power monitor API's](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor) and
implement an Interval function to check if time is more than 15 minutes then log out user

```
const {powerMonitor} = require('electron'); 
const idle = powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime() // it returns in seconds when I am writing this
console.log('Current System Idle Time - ', idle);
```

Comment: The OP asks for electron app idle time not the system idle time.