# Creating a closed Caption in an HTML Audio Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a method to add Closed Captioning to an HTML audio only tag. I am currently using the `<track>` tag, but it does not provide a caption box.

```
  <div id="audioCenter">
        <audio controls>
            <source src="~/Training/Compliance/ar/10165676.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <track kind="captions" label="English SubTitles" src="~/Training/Compliance/ar/10165676.mp3" srclang="en" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        <p style="color:white">This Section Has been Selected from Lesson 1 section 1 to allow the Test Taker to sample the audio</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: Did you manage to add CC to <audio> element? Asking because Mozilla doc says "The <audio> element doesn't directly support WebVTT. You will have to find a library or framework that provides the capability for you, or write the code to display captions yourself. One option is to play your audio using a <video> element, which does support WebVTT."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`<track>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) element `src` should point to a `.vtt` file, not `.mp3`. See also [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39563620/) at [Alternative for checking browser idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553729/alternative-for-checking-browser-idle/39563620#39563620)