# auto generate the transcript of video i.e subtitles and captions

Tags: javascript, html, transcription

Is there a way or any plugin who can generate transcript of video to play in website page. e.g the captions and subtitle of video in English language

Comment: @ewwink It is possible. JavaScript is software

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `SpeechRecognition()` and `VTTCue()` to transcribe audio output and create `TextTrack`s for the video.

See

- [SpeechRecognition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition)
- [Alternative for checking browser idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553729/alternative-for-checking-browser-idle/39563620?s=1|5.0409#39563620)

Comment: is it free service ?

Comment: @Asad Yes. Have you read the linked documentations? See also [How to use Web Speech API at chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013933/how-to-use-web-speech-api-at-chromium)