# How to add subtitles from a external source in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

I'm trying to add subtitles from an external source in a video html but I can't. I'm using the WebTorrent Technology, so, I'm streaming video torrents in my Browser and the `<track>` tag not works for me. Here's the code that I use: https://plnkr.co/edit/31RZSBETaAQgnCgZgKUt?p=preview
The code for subtitles it's this:

```
file.appendTo('body');
var video = document.querySelector("video");
var track = video.addTextTrack("subtitles", "prompt", "en");
track.mode = "showing";
});
```

Thanks, i hope that you can help me!

Comment: Function shows as not supported in any browser haven't seen this one so can't really speak to it:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_addtexttrack.asp

Comment: What is the issue with the code at linked plnkr?

Comment: Oh no, it´s not a issue with the code at linked plnkr. It's just that I want to add subtitles from an external source, and I don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you describe "doesn't works"? Have you created and linked to a corresponding `.vtt` file?

Comment: Yes, https://bitmovies.000webhostapp.com/subs.vtt

Comment: You know how to add that .vtt subtitles to the code?

Comment: @shaunhusain `.addTextTrack()` is supported at both Chromium/Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @guest271314 gotcha I wouldn't normally trust w3schools.com really but don't seem to see anything about it on MDN, where else should I be looking?

Comment: @shaunhusain See [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlmediaelement). You can use `"addTextTrack" in HTMLMediaElement.prototype` to check if `addTextTrack` is defined at the browser you are using, see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39563620/) at [Alternative for checking browser idle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39553729/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create or include a `<track>` element within HTML as a child of parent `<video>` element with `default` property set to `true`, `src` to to `.vtt` file, `kind` set to `"subtitles"`, `mode` set to `"showing"`, `label` set to `"Español"`, and `srclang` set to `"es"`

```
  file.appendTo('body');
  var video = document.querySelector("video");

  var track = document.createElement("track");
  track.mode = "showing";
  track.label = "Español";
  track.kind = "subtitles";
  track.srclang = "es";
  track.src = "subs.vtt";
  track.default = true;
  video.appendChild(track);
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/9MpJNHTB08RP6Lz3tvEb?p=preview