# Interactive video - timed click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have created clickable hotspots for a video using css and javascript, so that when the user clicks on the box a pop up will appear and the video pauses.

However I was wondering if I could time these elements so that they appear at certain points in the video.

I was thinking that I need to  trigger the display of the clickable areas at defined times but I'm not really sure how I could go about this.

I have included the code I used.

Hope this makes sense.

```js
var video1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    video1 = $ ('#video1');


    $('.box1').on('click', function(){
    playPauseVideo(('.persona1PopUp'));


    });

    $('.box2').on('click', function(){

    });

});


function playPauseVideo(popUp){

    if (video1[0].paused){
        video[0].play();
    } else {
        video1[0].pause();
        $.featherlight($(popUp));

    }

}
```

```css
body{
    background-color:#1e1e1e;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.descArea{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #c8c8c8;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.videoArea{
    position: relative;
}

.box1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(40, 169, 220, 0.3);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 630px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(207, 50, 53, 0.3);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox{
    display: none;
}

.longBtns{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Video</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Skeleton CSS & Featherlight -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/featherlight.css">
    <script src="js/featherlight.js"></script>

    <!-- Interaction CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/interaction.css">

    <!-- Interaction js -->
    <script src="js/interaction.js"></script>

    <!-- GreenSock -->
    <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

        <div class="row videoArea">
            <div class="box1"></div>
            <div class="box2"></div>
            <video id="video1" controls autoplay>
                <source src="../Interactive/media/Short Story Animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="row descArea">

            <h5>Video Title</h5>
            <p>This is the description</p>
            <div class="current">0:00</div>
            <div class="duration">0:00</div>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- End of Container -->



    <div class="lightbox persona1PopUp">
        <img src="images/Justin.jpg">
        <h5>Justins Hanks</h5>
        <p>Role: Development Manager</p>
        <p>Bio: Justin has been a manager for 4 years. sakjdhsakjdh askjdh ksajhd aksjh askjdhksajd askjhd askjhdkjsah </p>
        <p>Previous Experiences</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
            <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
            <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLMediaElement.addTextTrack()` or `<track>` element and one or more valid `.vtt` files to render captions at video playback at specific times; see [Alternative for checking browser idle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39553729/),  [How to add subtitles from a external source in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201103/how-to-add-subtitles-from-a-external-source-in-html5/).