# Display warning after X time of inactivity and logout after X+Y time javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, user-interface, session-timeout

I have seen many answers similar to this question.None helped me resolving this.
**Issue**- I want to display a warning message after 5 minutes of inactivity,If the user is still inactive post 5 minutes of warning, Page should automatically redirect to logoff.jsp.
I dont want to use Jquery here.It has to be done using Javascript only. **Help!!**

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 15; //seconds
 var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

 document.onkeypress = function() 
 {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };
 document.onclick = function() 
 {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };
 document.onmousemove = function()
 {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
 };

 window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

 function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        var answer = confirm("It's been long time you are idle.\nPlease click OK to continue session.\nTo close this session click Cancel.");
        if (answer) 
        {
            //document.location.href = "logout.html";   
            _idleSecondsCounter=0;
        }
        else{
            //window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
            document.location.href = "logoff.jsp";
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: So what's the problem

Comment: Page should automatically redirect after 5 mins if the user still hasn't selcted OK or Cancel option.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you cannot programmatically close `alert()` or `confirm()` or these modals. You've to make your own kind of box if you want to do that.

When you show `confirm()`, your JS execution is automatically paused. So you'll need to create your custom dialog box using HTML/CSS.

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
    el.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        // 5 minutes over. sign off user
    },duration);
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

tempAlert("We're signing you off in 5 minutes",5*60000);
```

Comment: Thanks Mohan ! Can we approach this using Jquery. I'm a beginner in Jquery still.If so, How can we ?

Comment: Isn't it more a comment than an answer?