# session destroy after count down timer reach 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

use countdown timer for  logout user,if user is inactive for 2hrs..

```
function Timer(duration, display)  {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt((timer /3600)%24, 10)
        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours +":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
        if(hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0){
            $.ajax({
              url:'../ajax/logoutuser.php',

              success: function(data){
                  console.log('logout');
              }
            });
        }else{
           --timer;
        }

    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var twentyFourHours = 1 * 1 * 3;
  var display = $('#time');


 Timer(twentyFourHours, display);


};
```

and since i cant call session destroy on jquery function i use ajax to make request..

```
<?php

require_once '../config/database.php';
require_once '../includes/dboperations/user.php';

$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();
$db =  new User($conn);

$user = json_decode($_SESSION["user"]);
        $db->offlineStatus($user->user_id);


        session_destroy();

        echo "<script>window.location.href = '../index.php'</script>";

?>
```

but what happens is, it doesnt call the session destroy function after making request. it runs the `console.log` inside success function..

is there a way to log out user if inactive for 2hrs

Comment: As far as I see, your inactivity detection forces user to refresh/reload page to be considered as active. Isn't it better to take inactivity as no action (no mouse move, no key pressed, no click)?

Comment: i dont have any idea on how to check that tho..but if you can give me an idea it would be better since that is what im trying to do.

Comment: If the very main reason is something client-side (eg. destroying cookies) you might want to go for a Javascript-solution (even tough personally I don't like it cause clien-side Javascript can be forged by the user). If it's something server-side you want to achieve, choose for server-side session destroy. Or both... 
I'd prefer server-side though b/c it's safer: record user activity in your php code and simply kick  user (destroy session) if activity (post/get etc.) time > max user idle time.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029518/2811746) for instance. There are many solutions on SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echo script from php file out it in success function of ajax code

```
success: function(data){
         console.log('logout');
         window.location.href = '../index.php';
}
```

Comment: but does it acctually destroy the session? it redirects me to my homepage since the session didn't destroy.. that's why i use window.location.href on echo to check if session_destroy will be called.

Comment: yes it will destroy session as per your php code calling during ajax

Comment: yeah i just messed up on my ajax request.. but it works.. now i have to figure out with no action at all.. like mouse move/click key press...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by php way. Something like

```
$expiry = 1800 ;//session expiry required after 30 mins
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST'] > $expiry)) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
$_SESSION['LAST'] = time();
```

Comment: but does the `$_SESSION['LAST'] refresh its value when page reloads?. cause what im actually trying do to using countdown timer it will only run once the page doesn't reload anymore..

Comment: if you have this code added to the common file, which is assuring each page load it will decide the log out in the backend. still, we can add timer function in front-end (JS) we can achieve it.