# Get System Idle time using browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fetch the system idle time using by browser. Is there an implemented solution for this scenario .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly#4029518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
var idleTime = 0;
var allowedIdleTime = 2000;
$(document).ready(function () {
        var idleInterval = setInterval(calculateTime, 1000); // 1 second
        $(window).focus(function (e) {
            if(idleTime>allowedIdleTime) {
                console.log('Last Idle Time was ' +idleTime+' ms' );
            }
        });
        $(window).blur(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
});
function calculateTime() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1000;
}
```

Here `allowedIdleTime` time can be set to avoid calling target operation before a specified interval.

Comment: Hi Jeet, Your answer for get idle time while we are not moving the mouse and keyboard within webpage document. But I need solutions for while I work with some other active window like notepad,Terminal or IDE ..etc . I need to fetch that idle time from browser