# How know if the user does not do anything using jQuery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, jquery-events

I have a code that shows a notifications box when there has occurred a new earthquake in the world. 
I want **reduce at an icon** if the user, for 20 seconds since the box appears, **does not do anything**

So if not `resize`,`scroll`,`click` and press button on keyboard.

Is there a fast way to do this? 
How can combine all these events?

I hope can you suggest me something :)

Comment: Do you have some code yet? Tried anything? As suggestion: set a timer on appearance. If something happens in this time, reset or quit the timer...

Comment: @LinkinTED not yet... but do you think that i write all events ?

Comment: I don't know if you do, I know I do... But please consider that this is a helping community, not a scripting from scratch community. So if you are looking for someone to make you the script, I don't think you'll find it here :)

Comment: i write "suggest me something" not "write code"...

Comment: I suggested you a timer :)

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved in this way:

```
        var notifiche_active= true;
        $(document).on('keypress click mousemove resize scroll',function(){
            notifiche_active = false;
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(notifiche_active == true){
                $('#notifiche_terremoti').hide();
                alert('nascondi');
            }
            notifiche_active= true;
        },20000);
```

I hope that here i write all EVENTS..

thanks all for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I have not enough reputation to answer in the commentary, so i am writing here. An example - you can write onclick, onkeydown and other events, then add "!" to before the statement with setTimeout.

Comment: Don't post commentary as answer. Having not enough rep doesn't mean you can just ignore the rules.