# Decrease idle time out using developer tools console in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

If we perform some activities like simple printing into console log does this decrease the idle time to prevent session time out of application.

My problem we use one web application which has very less idle time so ithere any tweak to prevent session time out due to inactivity

Comment: It would depend on how that website calculates idle time. If they are doing something along the lines of what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667555/5894241), there should be some way to work around that. Do you have any information about their definition of idle time?

Comment: console will have zero effect