# Im looking to add a timer until login pops up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some javascript that is for my login screen for this protected information but I want it to ask the person after being on the website for a certain amount of time for the password again.

```
      document.getElementById("forms").addEventListener("submit", 
       checkPswd, true);
                function checkPswd(){
                    var confirmPassword = "admin";
                    var password = 
                    document.getElementById("pswd").value;
                    if (password == confirmPassword){
                        window.location.href = "main.html";

                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Password is incorrect.");
                    }


                     //add prevent default
            event.preventDefault();
                }   
;
```

Comment: If you're doing this for security reasons, it needs to be handled by the back end. You can't trust that anything that happens on the client is accurate.

Comment: There is absolutely no security here.

Comment: Check this link :::: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top