# How can I implement session expiry based on users inactivity in django framework?

Tags: python, django

I am using django request.session.set_expiry() to expire session for a logged in user. But it expires session even though user is active.

```
    if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      request.session.set_expiry(60)
```

Comment: just follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029518/7887883 and replace reload to logout url. its a jquery code to track inactivity of user.

Comment: Is there any django method that can do this?

Comment: Try https://django-session-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I can't try that one. Strictly prohibited to use third party libraries/modules.