# Angular application logs out after refresh

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and made an app with login logout feature. After login when I refresh the browser, application automatically logs out. I can't understand how to use session. Also is there anyway my app automatically logs out after particular time if there's no activity?

[auth.service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLQq1.png)

[auth.gaurd.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQULc.png)

[login.component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGjXr.png)

Comment: you have to save your session token in either `cookies` or `localStorage`. and use it to determine if your session has expired or not

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code snippet for others to check. A screenshot or link to external code repo is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the session somewhere, cookie or localStorage for example

> I can't understand how to use session

here you're

```
// auth.service.ts

private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true");

login (user: User) {
   if (user.userName === "admin" && user.password === "admin") {
      localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
      localStorage.setItem("token", "add some unique token here");
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
   }
}
```

> Also is there anyway my app automatically logs out after particular time if there's no activity?

yes there's a way, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly) for example

**Sidenote** the code above is just an example please don't use it in production.

**update** here's a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3vug2g)

Comment: This code made my AuthGaurd (auth.gaurd) not work. Any better idea?

Comment: @nipun check the link in the answer

Comment: How can I activate the header only if I'm logged in?

<mat-toolbar id="mainToolbar" > <mat-icon (click)="onToolbarMenuToggle()" id="toolbarMenu">subject</mat-icon> <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span> <button mat-button (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button> </mat-toolbar>

Comment: @nipun You can use `*ngIf` attribute for example `<mat-toolbar *ngIf="isLogged"/>`, also I recommend you to take a look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs)

Comment: I know it might be getting frustrated for you but still I'm getting the issue while refreshing the page, my toolbar disappears. Any help?

Comment: create a GitHub repo with your source code and give me the link