# Refresh web Page on idle / inactivity

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a touch screen web kiosk (running Edge) that resets itself after idle timeout.
When no one touches the screen for 2 min (for example), it will refresh itself.
How can I do this with js? I want to use it on a local html page.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to run the reset function. Add event handlers for the interaction events that clears the old timer and starts a new one.

Comment: it seems already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: I suspect most public kiosks do this with code outside the browser that restarts the browser, rather than doing it with JavaScript.

Comment: To do it right you need to clear all the browsing data, so one user doesn't get the previous user's completions, credit cards, passwords, history, etc. There must be existing packages that are used by all the kiosks in hotels, airports, etc.

Comment: Don't try to roll your own if you're not sure of all the details, you'll create a privacy disaster.

Answer (score 2):

This code ended up working for me, tried many others:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725556/11185656

```
var idleTime;
$(document).ready(function () {
         reloadPage();
        $('html').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
            clearTimeout(idleTime);
            reloadPage();
        });
});
function reloadPage() {
    clearTimeout(idleTime);
    idleTime = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 10000);
}
```