# Redirecting Page with idle timer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page after the user is idle for 30 minutes. How do I do this? I'm horrible at JS so I haven't tried anything.

The idle timer code only shows how long the user has been idle for.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Test
    </title>
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="idle">
      <p class="timertext">
        <span class="secs"></span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script>
      let timer,
        currSeconds = 0;
      function resetTimer() {
        /* Hide the timer text */

        document.querySelector(".timertext").style.display = "none";

        /* Clear the previous interval */

        clearInterval(timer);

        /* Reset the seconds of the timer */

        currSeconds = 0;

        timer = setInterval(startIdleTimer, 1000);
      }
      window.onload = resetTimer;
      window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
      window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
      window.ontouchstart = resetTimer;
      window.onclick = resetTimer;
      window.onkeypress = resetTimer;

      function startIdleTimer() {
        /* Increment the 
                    timer seconds */

        currSeconds++;

        /* Set the timer text 
                    to the new value */

        document.querySelector(".secs").textContent = currSeconds;

        /* Display the timer text */

        document.querySelector(".timertext").style.display = "block";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Credits to Geeks for Geeks for original idle code

Comment: What about a simple `setInterval(() => { if (currSecconds > 30) window.location.href = "http://example.com" }, 1000)`?

Comment: I'll see if it works in about 30 mins

Comment: I dont think that works

Comment: currSecconds should be currSeconds. See this codesandbox: https://d9wkg.csb.app/

Comment: Okay! I'll try that

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126042/11575008).

```
timer = setTimeout(redirectUser , 30 * 60 * 1000);

function redirectUser() {
  window.location.href = 'https://mylink.com';
}
```

And when you're testing, just change the second parameter to `setTimeout` like so:

```
timer = setTimeout(redirectUser, 5000);
```

It's the amount of time in milliseconds before it executes the function passed as the first parameter.

```js
var timer;

function resetTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  timer = setTimeout(redirectUser, 30 * 60 * 1000);
}

function redirectUser() {
  window.location.href = 'https://redirecturl';
}

window.onload = resetTimer;
window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
window.ontouchstart = resetTimer;
window.onclick = resetTimer;
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Test
    </title>
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't detect idle time

Comment: I meant it as keep what you have, just replace the line with `setInterval` with the `setTimeout`, and use this `redirectUser`. Unless you mean you want to track the idle time somewhere on the website.

Comment: I'm sorry, I bad at JS. Can you show me what it would look like? Thanks!