# React JS delete cookie based on browser inactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to automatically logout the user based on inactivity of the user. I am trying to delete the cookies which store user token, but this is not working.
Can you Please provide me the better solution.?

Comment: Can you Please share all the approaches which you have tried till now.

Comment: I want to detect user inactivity on browser

Comment: Okay, I got your point, I have written the answer for you. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should first verify the browser's inactivity, afterwards you can delete the cookie as per your requirements. Following library is optional, hence it would be beneficial:

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';


const [cookies, setCookies, removeCookies] = useCookies(['token']);
function checkIdleness() {
var t;
window.onload = timerReset;
window.onmousemove = timerReset;
window.onmousedown = timerReset;  // catches touchscreen presses as well      
window.ontouchstart = timerReset; // catches touchscreen swipes as well 
window.onclick = timerReset;      // catches touchpad clicks as well
window.onkeydown = timerReset;
window.addEventListener('scroll', timerReset, true); // improved; see comments

function writeYourFunction() {
  // your function for too long inactivity goes here
  removeCookies('token', { path: '/' })
}

function timerReset() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(writeYourFunction, 10000);  // time is in milliseconds
}


}


checkIdleness();
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check the idleness of the browser.
For detecting idle time, refer to this Question
[How to detect idle time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript)
After that, you can delete the cookie as per your need.
For deleting the cookey, follow this link
[https://www.guru99.com/cookies-in-javascript-ultimate-guide.html#:~:text=JavaScript%20Delete%20Cookie,expires%20to%20a%20passed%20date](https://www.guru99.com/cookies-in-javascript-ultimate-guide.html#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20Delete%20Cookie,expires%20to%20a%20passed%20date).

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie you're trying to delete is an httpOnly cookie, which is often the case and a best practice for storing authorization tokens, you won't be able to delete it using client-side javascript. Instead, you'll need to make another request to your backend, which can remove the cookie.