# Javascript Event Listener when nothing is happening after a period of time

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I would ask if someone know an Event Listener, that start to work when there aren't pressed button on the Keyboard for a determined period of time, something like that:

```js
document.addEventListener('wait', myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a listener that will do that. So perhaps:

1. Set up a status variable that is reset when a key is pressed.
2. Create a delay function. In this example I'm returning a promise from the function that can be `awaited`.
3. When `main` is called it `awaits` the `delay` promise to be resolved. If no key has been pressed it calls a function and awaits for it to complete, then calls `main` again, otherwise no further action is taken.

```js
// Cache the output element used in `writer`
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

// Initialise the status
let status = false;

// Check for `keypress` events
document.addEventListener('keypress', () => status = true);

// Accepts an argument specifying how
// many milliseconds delay there will be
function delay(n) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), n);
  });
}

// Random function to test the delay works
function writer() {
  return new Promise(async res => {
    const str = 'Hello world!';
    for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
      await delay(250);
      output.textContent = str.substr(0, i);
    }
    res();
  });
}

// Wait 3 seconds. If no key has been pressed
// call the `writer` function. Reset the status, and
// call `main` again
async function main() {

  await delay(3000);

  if (!status) {
    console.log('No key pressed - calling writer()');
    await writer();
  } else {
    console.log('Key pressed - no further action');
  }

  status = false;
  main();

}

main();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) for this.

`setTimeout` runs a function after a specified period of time. It also returns an ID that can be passed to `clearTimeout`.

`clearTimeout` cancels the timeout associated with the ID that you give it.

You would call `setTimeout` to start the "idle timer", and store the timer ID in a variable. Then, if the user pressed a key (which you could detect using a `keypress` event listener) then you would use `clearTimeout` to cancel the timer (and maybe start it again).

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful answer here : [How to detect idle time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript)

You would use the `'keypress'` event. So basically create a timeout and reset it every time a key is pressed!

Hope it helps!