# Track user activity in electron window

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron

I have a simple electron app with a local startpage and links to specific websites. The task is to switch back to my local startpage when the user is idle for more then x minutes. I use an adaption of the fantastic script provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript) to track for idle time and it works great.

But if an Iframe or pdf is opened on one of the external pages tracking of idle time stops of course as long as the user moves inside this document.

Does anybody know a way to track user inputs (touch, mousemove, keydown...) inside the electron renderer window regardless of it's content?

Comment: There is no need to Track the user outside my electron window. But as long as electron has the focus and the mouse is inside the window I'd like to monitor if there is activity.